# How do I change what c++ redistributable my solution is using?

Tags: c++, windows, software-distribution

I have a exe that keeps erroring because its looking for 2008 redistributable and it needs to be on 2013. How do i change this so it uses 2013 instead?

Thanks

Comment: Recompile the executable to link to the 2013 redistributable. Probably much easier to download and install the 2008 redistibutable.

Comment: is there any settings i need to change. the issue is we don't want to install the 2008 version because the rest of the software is on 2013. I opened the sln in vs 2013 and rebuilt it, but it still gives me the error.

Comment: Did you rebuild all of the dependent `.dlls` that the project uses?

Comment: @drescherjm i did not. Will try that now tho.

Comment: Sorry guys this wasn't even my fault. Testers were using wrong files to test from. Rebuilding it in vs 2013 fixed this issue. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are blocked such that you cannot use VS2013 and rebuild the EXE in VS2013, you just need to find which exact VC++ runtime you'd need, and then download and install the same.

For example [this download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29) can be use to download **32-bit** version of VS2008, and probably just the **RTM** of VC2008. Your EXE might have been build on 64 bit, might have used particular service pack (or update, I don't know if there were any).